# Adding PSCustomObject to Array gives Error, but works fine when debugging the code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

When reading data from a CSV file and then trying to add a new custom object to the list I get an error when running the script, but when I try to debug the code I works as intended, and I can't figure out why it does work in debug mode, but not when run normally.

```
    $global:scanTime = Get-date
    $script:logfile_Database = Import-Csv -Path "${logSpace}\${CSV_logfileData}" -Delimiter ";"
    $currentLogfile = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($logfile.Path)\$($logfile.FileName)" -ErrorAction Stop
    $logfile_Data = [PSCustomObject]@{
        scanTime = $scanTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
        size = $currentLogfile.Length
    }
    $logfile_Database += $logfile_Data
```

Expected result:  Array with measurements with the latest measurement at the end.

Error when not in debug mode:

Error: Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

---

Update

Got it working now with the following update to the code, but I still would like to know why there is a difference in code execution between debug mode and normal mode.

```
    $global:scanTime = Get-date
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$script:logfile_Database = Import-Csv -Path "${logSpace}\${CSV_logfileData}" -Delimiter ";"
    $currentLogfile = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($logfile.Path)\$($logfile.FileName)" -ErrorAction Stop
    $logfile_Data = [PSCustomObject]@{
        scanTime = $scanTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
        size = $currentLogfile.Length
    }
    $logfile_Database.add($logfile_Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this depends on how many entries are already in your logfile.

If there's just *one* entry, `Import-Csv` will return a single `PSCustomObject` (note, I'm using `ConvertFrom-Csv` below, but `Import-Csv` works the same way):

```bsh
PS> $x = ConvertFrom-Csv "aaa, bbb, ccc`r`nxxx, yyy, zzz"
PS> $x.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

but if there's multiple lines in the csv file you get an array of `Object`s instead:

```bsh
PS> $x = ConvertFrom-Csv "aaa, bbb, ccc`r`nppp, qqq, rrr`r`nxxx, yyy, zzz"
PS> $x.GetType().FullName
System.Object[]
```

In the first case, PowerShell is telling you it doesn't know how to append a new entry onto a `PSCustomObject` because there's no `op_Addition` method defined on that type.

You can coerce the result of ConvertFrom-Csv / Import-Csv into an array in a few ways:

```bsh
PS> $x = @( ConvertFrom-Csv "aaa, bbb, ccc`r`nxxx, yyy, zzz" )
PS> $x.GetType().FullName
System.Object[]

PS> [object[]] $x = ConvertFrom-Csv "aaa, bbb, ccc`r`nxxx, yyy, zzz"
PS> $x.GetType().FullName
System.Object[]
```

or, as you've found:

```bsh
PS> [System.Collections.ArrayList] $x = ConvertFrom-Csv "aaa, bbb, ccc`r`nxxx, yyy, zzz"
PS> $x.GetType().FullName
System.Collections.ArrayList
```

And PowerShell knows how to do a `+=` on all of these types...