# Adding PSCustomObject to Array gives Error, but works fine when debugging the code in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I know this question is already answered, but that question didn't answered my question.
The link is [Adding PSCustomObject to Array gives Error, but works fine when debugging the code in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640581/adding-pscustomobject-to-array-gives-error-but-works-fine-when-debugging-the-co)
When I am trying to run the script its executing fine in debug mode but its failing if I am executing directly.

```
$path = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$output_File = $path + "\$outputFile_Name"
$report = @()

function Folder-Access
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string]$prod_path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$non_prod_path
    )

    Write-Host "`$prod_path value: $prod_path"
    Write-Host "`$non_prod_path value: $non_prod_path"

    try {
    
        $prod_acl = get-acl $prod_path
        $nonProd_acl = Get-Acl $non_prod_path
        $arr = @()



        foreach ($non_prod_usr in ($nonProd_acl.access) ) {
   
            $x = $non_prod_usr.IdentityReference.Value
            $arr += $x
        
            }

       foreach ($usr in ($prod_acl.Access)){
        

            $dirObj = New-Object psobject
            if ($usr.IdentityReference.Value -in $arr) {
            
                echo "Do Nothing."
            
            } else {
            
                if ($usr.IdentityReference.Value -ne 'BUILTIN\Administrators') {

                    if ($usr.IdentityReference.Value -ne 'S-1-5-21-2554127390-2720852439-1129525235-1959308') {
                      
                      $properties = [ordered]@{'Foldername'=$non_prod_path; 'AD Group'=$usr.IdentityReference.Value;
                                               'Permissions'=$usr.Filesystemrights}

                      echo "Do Something."               
                      $usr.IdentityReference.Value
                     
                      #$dirObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Foldername" -Value $non_prod_path
                      #$dirObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'AD Group' -Value $usr.IdentityReference.Value
                      #$dirObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Permissions' -Value $usr.Filesystemrights
                      #$report += $dirObj
                      $report += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $properties
                      
                     }
                }
                
              }
                #$report += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $properties              
                
            } $report | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Powershell\output.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
             
         
    } 
    catch { 
    
            Write-Host "Error occured " + $_ -ForegroundColor Red
            
            }
}

function executionTimeForSourcePath {

    try {
            
            $Prod_Folder_Path = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $prod_path -Recurse -Force 
            
            $Prod_Folder_Path | ForEach-Object {

            if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.FullName))){
        
                $path = $_.FullName
                $folderName = $path.Replace($prod_path + '\',"")
        
                if (-Not (Test-Path "$non_prod_path\$folderName")){
                    
                    try {
        
                        New-Item -ItemType Dir -Path "$non_prod_path\$folderName" -ErrorAction Stop
        
                            if (Test-Path "$non_prod_path\$folderName"){
        
                                Folder-Access -prod_path $path -non_prod_path "$non_prod_path\$folderName"
                            }
                        } 
                    catch {
                            Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
                            }
                    }
                
                ElseIf (Test-Path "$non_prod_path\$folderName") {
                
                    Folder-Access -prod_path $path -non_prod_path "$non_prod_path\$folderName"
                    
                    }


                } }

         } catch { $_ }

}


echo "Script started.."
executionTimeForSourcePath
```

Would be great if someone can guide me here please. I tried all the possible ways but none worked for this.
The error is
**Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.
PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.**

Comment: Please post the exact error message (even if it's similar to the one in the linked answer)

Comment: Is it possible that VS Code is configured to use a different version of PowerShell (View > Command Palette... > PowerShell: Show Session Menu)?  It may help to post your VS Code [user or workspace launch.json configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations), or your [global launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration) for review.  Profile scripts may also account for the runtime differences.  Worth a mention.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added the error.